# How can I fix a System.Security.SecurityException error in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, security, mscorlib

I have a Visual Studio application that I inherited (VS2010) and have converted to a more recent version (VS2013).  Outside of a few minor modifications (database connection string, crystal report source file), the application is the same.  This is a windows forms application that allows the user to choose a report from a SQL database, and displays the data in crystal reports.

When I execute the application as an administrator, the winform is displayed and I can select a report to view from the database (everything works OK).  When I execute the application as a standard user, I'm immediately notified that the application has stopped working.  This also occurs if I choose to run the application as Administrator under the standard user account.

The log file is as follows:

"System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Requested registry access is not allowed."

This occurs on my development machine (Windows 7 64-bit) as well as the end user machine (Windows 7 32-bit).  I've tried several suggestions found online including:

1. Editing the registry to give "full control" permissions to both the ASPNET and local user account on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES\EVENTLOG folder.
2. Verifying that the two custom *.dlls used in the application have the correct access in the registry (everyone group, users group both with read access).  One of the libraries attempts to open a key and read the associated values.
3. Place the "ASPNET" user in the administrator group (although this is not an IIS application, I thought I'd give it a shot).
4. User Account Control has been disabled.

My expectation would be that when the local user (part of the users group only) executes the application, the winform will appear to list an available reports to select from.

I'm at a loss and have started to run out of ideas.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, the error reports: `"Requested registry access is not allowed."`. It looks like you're trying to access a Registry key that the current user doesn't have permission to access/modify. Possibly, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: You say Winforms but then mention ASPNET, can you please elaborate why you're dealing with both a ASP.NET *web* application and a Winforms application at the same time here?

Comment: In general there are two ways of fixing security problems like this: 1) Giving the user/program the required access, or 2) Don't try to do something you don't have access to. Do you know where/why it attempts to read the registry? For instance, could it be that it opens the registry requesting full (write) access, when it only needs to read?

Comment: The Windows Forms application is a program that was developed by my company to create reports from a SQL database.  There is another application (Siemens WinCC) that resides on the computer as well - It requires IIS to be enabled, although that particular feature isn't being used within the application.  This is a stand-alone pc that has no connection to the internet or local area network.

When I googled the error messages, most of the solutions focused on a web application / ASPNET issue... and although we're not making use of this in our winforms application, I attempted the solutions.

Comment: The msi creates a registry subkey within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE that has a few values: debug level, days to retain record, etc.  When the application crashes, it's attempting to read the debug level, which is the first read from the registry.  This is a string value (1-5) that determines the detail at which debug messages are logged.  Also of note, if I add this user to the Administrators group, I have no issue.

Comment: Local non-administrator users have only direct access to the current `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` can be accessed by administrators and software that `runas` adminitrative accounts. As installers do.

Comment: This particular executable's compatibility properties are setup to 'run as administrator'.

I believe I may have found the solution - The registry subkey that is created had read-only permissions for the 'users' group.  The application appeared to crash on a registry read, which I would not have expected.  When I set the user group permissions to 'full control' the application runs on my development machine.  I intend to try this on the deployment machine tomorrow.

Comment: Why not eliminate the use of the registry all together and use the app.config file instead?